# Windows vista reinstall on a new HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, reinstall, dell-optiplex

I have a dell optiplex 320, installed with vista business. Unfortunately the HDD is packing up so I need to get a new one to put in to it. I have created a system image backup so should be able to get it back to its current state when vista is installed on the new HDD. The issue is that dell have put the 'recovery discs' on the HDD that is currently failing. Does anyone have any suggestions of how I could install vista business on the new HDD using this partition as I doubt dell would give me any free support. Thanks =)

Comment: sorry, whats that? i see it on my profile but what does it mean?

Comment: You need to start accepting answers if you want informed help here at SuperUser, go to your user profile and start accepting some answers to your previous posts...http://superuser.com/users/44435/sammy

Comment: It means when someone answers your question and it helped solve your problem or question, you need to mark that particular answer as "accepted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a system image backup, restore it to the new drive then restore from the second partition of the new drive?

Alternatively, install the new drive along side the old one and try a restore onto the new drive (preferably before the disk fails!).